# How do I set the height of nested divs with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a [simple jQuery function](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Equal-Heights/blob/master/jQuery.equalHeights.js) to set the height of an immediate child  tag.  I need to modify this to go after nested  tags as well.  For instance:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="panel green">
            // content panel 1 200px high based on content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="panel green">
            // content panel 2 250px high based on content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="panel green">
            // content panel 3 150px high based on content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For this row, all panels should be the same height.  Right now if I call `$('.four').equalHeights();` it will only set the height on the first content panel.  I need it to get the heights of panels 1, 2 and 3 then go back and set the max height of all panels in the row to the largest height in the row, in this case 250px.

If I try `$('row').equalHeights()` this doesn't work either.

I have tried setting `display: table-cell;` although adds additional overhead for styling.

To clarify, for each "row" I need to set the height of all panels.  If I have 3 different rows, I don't want all of 9 panels to be set to the max height found in 1 row.  All rows are independent of each other.

Comment: which jquery version are you using?

Comment: Frankly? I would use a `display:table-cell` here and be done with it.

Comment: @awolff I always assume the latest version unless known otherwise.

Comment: @JanDvorak i ask it because `$.browser` has been removed since jq 1.9. Anyway, using your suggestion should fix OP's issue, I guess

Comment: Are you trying this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/GYbZ9/2/

Comment: @JanDvorak I attempted that prior and with all the other styles on this particular site, I've decided to stay away from that due to some considerable css refactoring.

Comment: @AamirAfridi this works although the panels need to be grouped in a row.  So if I have 2 or 3 different groups of panels, this will go through all of them and get the largest, which is not ideal.

Comment: Sorry what??? you want to find the tallest in each group and than assign that height to all .panel in the same group? Modify my fiddle to explain your question.

Comment: @AamirAfridi take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GYbZ9/3/.  It shows 2 rows (or groups) of panels.  The second row of panels should be around 220px in height but its getting the largest value of 280px from the last panel in the first row.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/GYbZ9/4/ now?

Comment: Cool. Posted as answer. If you happy, accept or please ask if you still having issues :)

Comment: FYI, alot shorter version of his answer in my answer, as well as full-fledged plugin ifnya want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/GYbZ9/4/

Here is the simple code:

```
$('.row').each(function(){
    var $panels = $(this).find('.panel');
    var tallest = 0;
    //find tallest
    $panels.each(function () {
        var ph = $(this).height();
        if (ph > tallest) tallest = ph;
    }); 
    $panels.height(tallest);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
$(".row").equalHeights()
```

see this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p55wx/): in this example you need to click the `Set Height` button to trigger the function.

I gave an height/colour to each div to better show how it works.

Answer (score 0):

***Update*** Based on comments I went back and read and seeing the solution you want, I took my final plugin scheme and showed how to do exactly the same thing from yours and Aamir's comment. His answer, however, is basically the same thing as my first suggest below the line:

With Plugin:

```
$('.row').each(function(i) { $(this).find('.panel').equalHeights() });
```

#### Example

---

---

This is pretty easy. Just find the tallest one in a matched set, then set everything to that height. Or if you want to use a given height, Use that!

Like so:

```
var mh = 0;
$(".columns").each(function(i) { mh = mh > $(this).height() ? mh : $(this).height(); })
.height(mh);
```

### Example

Or, if you want it as a quick and dirty jQuery method:

```
$.fn.equalHeights = function (e) {
    var mh = 0;
    $(this).each(function(i) { mh = mh > $(this).height() ? mh : $(this).height(); });
    return $(this).height(mh);
};

// use as:
$(".columns").equalHeights();
```

### Example

**|OR|**

If you want it as a full jQuery plugin for use such as:

```
$(".four").equalHeights();  //  set all elements matching selector to height of tallest

$(".four").equalHeights(100);   //  set all elements matching selector to height of integer given

$(".four").equalHeights('200'); //  set all elements matching selector to height of string given

//  Same as top 3 but written alternatly in accordance with jQuery mark-up style
$.equalHeights(".four"); || $.equalHeights($(".four"));
$.equalHeights($(".four"), 100);
$.equalHeights($(".four"), '200');
```

Simply add the following full plugin:

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.equalHeights) {
        $.extend({
            equalHeights: function() {
                var args = arguments,
                    elm,
                    mh = 0;
                if (args.length) {
                    for (x in args) {
                        switch (typeof args[x]) {
                            case 'number':
                                mh = args[x];
                                break;
                            case 'object':
                                if (args[x] instanceof jQuery) elm = args[x];
                                break;
                            case 'string':
                                if (!elm) {
                                    if ($(args[x]).length) elm = $(args[x]);
                                    else if (!mh) if (args[x].replace(/\D/g, '')) mh = args[x].replace(/\D/g, '');
                                }
                                else if (!mh) if (args[x].replace(/\D/g, '')) mh = args[x].replace(/\D/g, '');
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (elm instanceof jQuery) {
                    if (!mh) elm.each(function(i) { mh = mh > $(this).height() ? mh : $(this).height(); });
                    return elm.height(mh);
                }
                else {
                    return 'Error: Cannot find Selector';
                }
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({
            equalHeights: function() {
                var args = [$(this)];
                if (arguments.length) for (x in arguments) args.push(arguments[x]);
                return $.equalHeights.apply($, args);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

### Example

Compiled version of plugin:

```
(function($){$.equalHeights||($.extend({equalHeights:function(){var a=arguments,c,b=0;if(a.length)for(x in a)switch(typeof a[x]){case "number":b=a[x];break;case "object":a[x]instanceof jQuery&&(c=a[x]);break;case "string":c?b||a[x].replace(/\D/g,"")&&(b=a[x].replace(/\D/g,"")):$(a[x]).length?c=$(a[x]):b||a[x].replace(/\D/g,"")&&(b=a[x].replace(/\D/g,""))}return c instanceof jQuery?(b||c.each(function(a){b=b>$(this).height()?b:$(this).height()}),c.height(b)):"Error: Cannot find Selector"}}),$.fn.extend({equalHeights:function(){var a=[$(this)];if(arguments.length)for(x in arguments)a.push(arguments[x]);return $.equalHeights.apply($,a)}}))})(jQuery);
```